# Understanding intra-thread semantics

Tags: java, multithreading, java-memory-model

Could you explain in simple words what "the program satisfies intra-thread semantic" means? Is it possible to provide simple examples of programs which satisfy and which don't satisfy such semantics?

Comment: I would assume "intra-thread" means single threaded. However, without context it would be very hard to say.  It is nearly impossible to write code which is not single threaded safe. Note: lazySet() is an exception.

Comment: @PeterLawrey actually iirc the java memory model JSR (133) kind of defines what "intra-thread" means

Comment: @MateuszDymczyk I think they are talking about the same thing.  It is rarely a problem as it would be really surprising if this was no the case.

Comment: @PeterLawrey the following context are giiven: _he actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics of that thread. Such program obeys intra-thread semantics..._

Comment: @St.Antario Yes, I read that as meaning that anything which can be read in place in a thread can be read at any other piece of code in the same thread.  AtomicXxxx.lazySet() is the only exception I can think of.

Comment: ```weakCompareAndSet```'s doc is also very fishy and might violate the intra-thread semantics but I'm not 100% sure, never dug into it that much

Comment: Do you mean "intra-thread semantics" as defined in the [JLS sec 17.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4)? If so then the definition is there, though I understand why you'd want it explained in simple words. :-)

Comment: @StuartMarks Yes, the definition is not quite clear for me. I'd like to look at an example.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The notion of *intra-thread semantics* is discussed in the [JLS section 17.4](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4), which covers the Java Memory Model. The JMM is a set of requirements and constraints on the execution of Java programs by JVMs. Here's the relevant section of text from 17.4:

> The memory model determines what values can be read at every point in the program. The actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics of that thread, with the exception that the values seen by each read are determined by the memory model. When we refer to this, we say that the program obeys *intra-thread semantics*. Intra-thread semantics are the semantics for single-threaded programs, and allow the complete prediction of the behavior of a thread based on the values seen by read actions within the thread. To determine if the actions of thread t in an execution are legal, we simply evaluate the implementation of thread t as it would be performed in a single-threaded context, as defined in the rest of this specification.

This means that, as far as a single thread is concerned, the values visible in objects' fields are either the fields' initial values (zero, false, or null) or are values that this thread has previously written.

This is so obvious as to be elementary; why bother stating it?

Consider a single-threaded Java program with a few `int` fields:

```
field1 = 1;                // 1
field2 = 2;                // 2
field3 = field1 + field2;  // 3
```

then clearly the value of `field3` must be 3. This is because the values visible in `field1` and `field2` at line 3 *must* reflect the earlier values written at lines 1 and 2. It would be incorrect if the initial value of zero for `field1` or `field2` were used in the computation at line 3, since the assignment of those fields occurs earlier in the program than the computation.

What is less obvious are the constraints that are *not* present. For example, there is no constraint here over the ordering of the *writes* of `field1` and `field2`. The JVM could execute line 2 before line 1 and the result of the program would be the same. Or, it could delay the writes to `field1` and `field2` and keep these values in registers, and do register-based addition at line 3. The actual writes of all the fields could be delayed until much later. Or they could even be omitted entirely if the values are subsequently overwritten by this thread. Again, the outcome of the program would be the same.

And that's the point: JVMs are free to rearrange the execution of a program (mainly so that it can run faster), but only as long it doesn't change the results of that program if it were run single-threaded. These constraints are referred to as *intra-thread semantics*. Any rearrangements that don't violate intra-thread semantics are permitted.

(Note that the paragraph quoted above talks about a "program that obeys intra-thread semantics" but what it really means is the *execution* of the program obeys intra-thread semantics. Text in later sections, such as 17.4.7, is more precise, referring to whether an *execution* of a program obeys intra-thread consistency or whether a *set of actions performed* is in accord with intra-thread semantics.)

Comment: It is interesting whta does mean "... with the exception that the values seen by each read are determined by the memory model" in the context of your example?

Comment: @Vitaly It doesn't mean all that much. Looking just at the semantics of the example program, it assigns *variables* "field1" and "field2" and then uses values from those variables in a computation to assign to variable "field3". Adding the memory model to this means that the assignments to "field1" and "field2" generate *write* operations, and their use in the expression means that the generate *read* operations followed by a *write* operation to "field3". Note that I've shifted vocabulary from variable assignment to memory read and write operations. That's the impact of the memory model.

Comment: Yes. But the statement seems confusing: "The memory model determines ... ... are determined by the memory model". We have circular reference to "The memory model" expression. It seems to me it is easier to read original JSR-133 specification than JLS.

Comment: @Vitaly I agree the wording is confusing. But it's also making an important but subtle point. The second sentence is drawing the distinction between the "semantics of that thread" and the additional requirements of the memory model. If the variables in question were local variables instead of fields, the semantics of the thread would be the same. However, applying the memory model is completely different, as assignments to, and using values of local variables generates no memory operations at all.

Comment: @StuartMarks __assignments to, and using values of local variables generates no memory operations at all.__ It sounds a bit confusing to me. What do you mean by memory opertions? The operations that memory model are concerned about (i.e. actions on heap memory)

Comment: @St.Antario Yes, memory operations are basically those that operate on the heap; essentially loads and stores from and to fields. Local variables exist on stacks, which are local to each thread. Therefore, they don't participate in the memory model.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break this down: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4

> <sup>**1**</sup> The memory model determines what values can be read at every point in the program. <sup>**2**</sup> The actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics of that thread, <sup>**3**</sup> with the exception that the values seen by each read are determined by the memory model. <sup>**4**</sup> When we refer to this, we say that the program obeys intra-thread semantics. Intra-thread semantics are the semantics for single-threaded programs, and allow the complete prediction of the behavior of a thread based on the values seen by read actions within the thread

**1.**
`The memory model determines what values can be read at every point in the program`

It means the JMM have rules for visibility and ordering that dictates the values for reads - rules that haven't been defined yet but makes the reader aware that they exist (they explain in **3** and **4** how it relates to intra-thread semantics)

**2.**
`The actions of each thread in isolation must behave as governed by the semantics of that thread`

It does not define what is "isolation" in this context, nor what is "semantics of that thread" but they probably meant Actions that do not fall under inter-thread actions, so all actions done by a thread that don't influence other threads will be read line by line (semantics of thread). Their "definition" for intra-thread actions (sort of, they only give an example) is:

"[This specification is only concerned with inter-thread actions. We do not need to concern ourselves with intra-thread actions (e.g., adding two local variables and storing the result in a third local variable)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-17.html#jls-17.4.2)" - ie any action that won't effect any shared memory.

**3.**
`with the exception that the values seen by each read are determined by the memory model.`

It means that the JMM apply its rules even when a thread executes code that have no influence on any other thread (**2**) - it dictates the values of these reads.

**4.**
`When we refer to this, we say that the program obeys intra-thread semantics. Intra-thread semantics are the semantics for single-threaded programs, and allow the complete prediction of the behavior of a thread based on the values seen by read actions within the thread`

To sum it up, they are saying - **If you have a thread that perform an action in isolation, meaning manipulates (read or write) data not in any shared memory. the value of reads in that code would still be *decided by the JMM and all of it (complete) would be known to that same thread** - This is what it means to obey intra-thread semantics

---

They almost implicitly describe here Sequential Consistency (SC) without actually saying it, the only missing part is inter-thread actions - This is described to be used later on in Program Order (*decided by the JMM) which needed all the definitions here to define when is SC used.

Program orders is the rule they kept mentioning without naming before, it says that if you look at all (total) the actions (intra and inter) in a thread and consider them as intra-thread semantic then they are all considered Sequential Consistent.

---

- You can understand what is SC by reading [Stuart Marks answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25728540/2870975)
- As a side note I just have to say the phrasing in JLS for JMM is horrendous, they could not have made it more confusing if they tried to.